# Why is UIButton blurry when creating programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i created a uibutton like so:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(280, 320, 100, 30);
[button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

and the button's text looks edgy, someone know why?

Comment: can you show something which type do u need the output'

Comment: do you mean to say it is transparent? If it is so check either the button or it's parent view's alpha.

Comment: @sargeras could you answer my other question you were on earlier?

Comment: Did you tried the UIButtonTypeSystem?

Comment: yes just did, no fix.

Comment: did you used any font?

Comment: no no font has been used

Comment: does it matter that its being created in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: http://imgur.com/HeWvdYl  on the right is a button from storyboard, on the left is a button i created

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

to

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                                                        ^^^^^^
```

All will be good..

Comment: I changed it to UIButtonTypeCustom and it's still edgy

Comment: okay i will, also does it matter that its in a cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: http://imgur.com/HeWvdYl 
on the right is a button from storyboard, on the left is a button i created

Comment: @farhan : all is fine... I feel you are using iPhone 6s simulator and you have zoom to minimum level... press CMD+1 and see how this looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving Font :

```
 // Configure the cell...
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeu-CondensedBold" size:16];
    button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```